# Null reference from MySQL driver module from taskpane.js a Microsoft Office Add-In

Tags: mysql, node.js, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to access a MySQL database from a Microsoft Office Add-In.  I can get the Add-In to work in MsWord, but when I try to use the MySQL Node.js driver, the "mysql" object shows up as null at runtime.

I added this at the beginning of taskpane.js:

```
import { mysql } from 'mysql';

did the following:
npm install mysql
npm audit fix
npm install @types/mysql
added the following to webpack.config.js "target: 'node',"
```

and later in the code, when I run it this fires and shows "mysql undefined":

```
 if (!mysql) {
  context.document.body.insertParagraph("mysql undefined", Word.InsertLocation.end);
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work, since you're trying to use a server library `mysql` in your front-end. While both are written in javascript, the environments they are working on are very different.

Diagram below explains it pretty neatly - sourced from [this website](https://bezkoder.com/react-node-express-mysql/) which I'm recommending you to check out.

[image]

In essence, for react library, you are using node.js as a *.jsx or *.js *build helper, packaging runner, etc..* so end result should be just a javascript file. Something like `main.123456.js` if you're using create react app's default build. That file will be meaningful in browser context, since you'll have DOM items here, HTML specific stuff.

For MySQL library - you are using node.js as a HTTP server. That won't have access to the DOM, but because it's running as a process on some compute unit, it'll provide you different capabilities, which enable your MySQL connection to work.

`office.js` operates in browser context, you're basically writing your app with react and just referencing some office.js APIs.
That means the line below belongs to your react app:

```js
context.document.body.insertParagraph("mysql undefined", Word.InsertLocation.end);
```

Your data from MySQL needs to come from your server though. You can use node.js as a server, that way you'll be able to use the MySQL library that you've imported from NPM. [This tutorial walks you through how to setup a very simple server.](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp)

That means this line

```js
import { mysql } from 'mysql';
```

and the sql connection belongs to the server side running on node.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That explains what’s going on, or not as the case may be.  But where would this simple node.js server reside, and where would I kick it off from?  It would need to be part of an end user solution.

Comment: Ah, so the server piece is running on the cloud side, i.e. Azure?

Comment: @PaulKaplan yes exactly.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Mavi Domates.  Implemented a REST api server on the Azure side (and ran into the CORS issue and dealt with that) and it's working beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

You need ti declare the variable first

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  database: 'satavasename',
  port: 3306,
  ssl: true
});
```